# Cannot create Swipe View implementing Android View Pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Trying to implement a view pager to swipe views for built in swipe gestures but while doing so it says at

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));
```

MyAdapter(android.app.FragmentManager) in My Adapter cannot be applied  to android.support.v4.FragmentManager

similarly at `return new NewsFragment();`

Required : an android.support.v4.FragmentManager Found:com.example.prabhukonchada.ebolamyapp.NewsFragment

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));
    }

    public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(position == 0)
            {
               return new NewsFragment();
            }else
            {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Fragment (NewsFragment) extends android.support.v4.Fragment, you are probably importing android.app.Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

go through these 2 links and download samples.
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html or
http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/